# a word for the sound a person makes when knocked down

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, onomatopoeia

Working on a scene where a character is repeatedly struck down by having objects thrown at her, starting the scene with the sound she would make after being hit with a ball made of solid ice.

Comment: Sounds like what? Can you link to audio/video examples?

Comment: It’s probably something like *uummpf*

Comment: If it were me it would probably be "Shit!"

Comment: [Ba Dum Tss!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zXDo4dL7SU)

Comment: Are you looking for a word that one of your characters would pronounce? If it is just for directions/description, why do you need to find the right onomatopoeia? Not that you shouldn't; just wondering what the use case really is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the *vocal* sound the person makes, then perhaps [***oof***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/oof). From Oxford Dictionaries:

> EXCLAMATION
>   Expressing discomfort, as from sudden exertion or a blow to one's body.

Example usage:

> he gloated, as he formed a large icy snowball in his fat fingers. Then he said, **”Oof!”** A large, hard snowball had caught him in the stomach. (Merv Lambert, *Beware of the Emu!*, 2012)

I think you're looking for dialogue, but if you're looking for narration you might still be able to use this.

It is also occasionally used as a verb, especially in indirectly reported speech:

> “I don't—” she began, then **“oofed”** as the wraith suddenly became corporeal and shoved her back a few feet. (Scott Ciencin, *Age of Unreason*, 2012)

Finally, it might possibly be echoic enough that you could also use it for the physical sound of the ice hitting her body, especially if she's wearing a puffy coat.